# Powershell GET-PSSession output Username as Listbox

Tags: powershell, session, listbox, output

if i enter the following invoke-command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTE-COMPUTER -scriptBlock {query session} -credential CREDENTIALS  | Select-String PART-OF-USERNAME
```

i get the output in commandline like:

```
SITZUNGSNAME      BENUTZERNAME       ID  STATUS 
>services                             0  Getr.                       
 console                              1  Verb.                       
 rdp-tcp#61        User1              2  Aktiv                       
 rdp-tcp#93        User2              3  Aktiv                       
 rdp-tcp#35        User3              4  Aktiv
```

Now it should only displayed the username in a listbox like:

```
# Listbox

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,60) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$listBox.Height = 350

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("User1")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("User2")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("User3")
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
```

[static output (example picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG0Vd.png)

But we want display dynamic all user which are logged in.

Has anyone an idea to show the commandline output as listbox like the example above (example picture)?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Julian! 
First thing you need to do is parse the output of `query session` and get it into a set of objects.  I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593325/powershell-commandnotfoundexception) for parsing that simplifies the process.

Next you need to iterate through that list and add each user name to the listbox. This should work - if you replace 'localhost' with your target computer:

```
Get-ComputerSessions 'localhost' | %{ [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_.Username) }
```

Comment: To add the `Get-ComputerSessions` function you'll need to run the script in the linked example. `Get-ComputerSessions` will parse the output of `query session` and make objects out of it that can be piped to `Out-GridView`: 
`Get-ComputerSessions -Computer "localhost" | Out-GridView `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggesstion but in does not work for me. "Get-ComputerSessions" is not a part of Cmdlet, function, etc. pp"

But i have found a other solution to fill my Listbox:

```
$sessions = Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME -scriptBlock {query.exe user /server:'localhost'} -credential CREDENTIALS | Select-String SEACHSTRING | sort-object
```

and

```
[void] $listBox.Items.AddRange($sessions)
```

OR (**my favourite**)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME -scriptBlock {query session} -credential CREDENTIALS | %{ [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_) } | Select-String SEARCHSTRING | sort-object
```

But i want only display the Username and (optional) the state of the rdp user.

It should looks like:

```
User1            active
User2            disconnected
```

The origin output includes some more information as i need. Example which also does not work for me:

Is it possible to make a "table" or "grid-view" and put them into the listbox? See example above.

Thanks a lot!